# Override Java method with complex type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement [JsonHttpResponseHandler#onSuccess](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html#onSuccess(int,%20org.apache.http.Header[],%20org.json.JSONArray)). When I use:

```
fun onSuccess(status: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONArray?)
```

I get an accidental override error, but when I add the `override` modifier, I get an `onSuccess overrides nothing` error. Am I doing something wrong, or have I discovered a bug in the Kotlin compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using "Override Methods" (`^O` on Mac), it will suggest the correct signature.

I suppose that it is

```
fun onSuccess(status: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, response: JSONArray?)
```

but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Great, that worked. Override methods is cmd-O by default, not ctrl-O, though.

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting the the default keymap is "Mac OS X", not "Mac OS X 10.5+". The latter is much more convenient to my taste, btw

Answer (score 2):

In Kolint M9, you have more flexibility in overriding Java methods about the nullability.  This is one of the things people get wrong the most, not seeing that the Java parameters might be NULL from Kotlin's perspective.  In M9 you can receive the parameters how you wish Kotlin to treat the Nullability rather than how they are actually seen from Java perspective.  So if you know the parameter is never null, you can receive it without the ?.  Previously that would result in a mismatch for checking if you actually overrode the method and give an error, now it is considered equivalent.